# Postgresql Group by

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I created a table in postgresQL like
[image]

Now I ran a query like::

```
SELECT name
FROM emp.company
GROUP BY name
```

And I am getting output like

[image]

I am unable to get it whats exactly happening over here.

Comment: It's exactly the same result as `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM emp.company`

Comment: And what output did you expect? And why?

Answer (score 3):

That's basically what grouping does. It displays every unique occurrence of the column(s) in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Commonly used with aggregate functions.